# Combine the result of 3 SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I've had troubles when trying to combine the result of 3 queries:

[image: result so far]

It's the result of 3 queries joined with union, they all pick datas in the same tables except for the last column and I'd like to have the result in one row, which would give me the result 17 in this case but I can't make it works...Any ideas?

thanks

edit: here is the code of the 3 queries used with union from the result above:

```
select distinct SSN_ID, 
            TME_ID, 
            TME_LIBELLE, 
            convert(varchar,ssn_date_debut,103) as 'Debut',
            CONVERT (varchar,ssn_date_fin,103) as 'Fin',
            SSN_NB_JOURS,
            COUNT (atr_id) as 'Total'
from SESSION
join INSCRIPTION on INS_SSN_ID = SSN_ID
join ACTEUR on INS_ATR_ID = ATR_ID
join theme on tme_id = ssn_tme_id
join ETAT_SESSION on esn_id = ssn_esn_id
join LIEU_SESSION on LSN_SSN_ID =ssn_id
join LIEU on LEU_ID = LSN_LEU_ID
where INS_DT_CONVOCATION is not null
and SSN_ESN_ID = 15
    and SSN_JOURNEE_ETUDE = 1 
    and LEU_NOM is not null
    and year(ssn_date_debut) = YEAR(GETDATE())
 group by SSN_ID,TME_ID,TME_LIBELLE,ssn_date_debut,ssn_date_fin,SSN_NB_JOURS,ins_ssn_id

union

 select distinct SSN_ID, 
                TME_ID, 
            TME_LIBELLE, 
            convert(varchar,ssn_date_debut,103) as 'Debut',
            CONVERT (varchar,ssn_date_fin,103) as 'Fin',
            SSN_NB_JOURS,
            COUNT (atr_id) as 'Total'
from SESSION
join SESSION_FORMATEUR on ASN_SSN_ID = SSN_ID 
join ACTEUR anim on  anim.ATR_ID = asn_atr_id
join theme on tme_id = ssn_tme_id
join ETAT_SESSION on esn_id = ssn_esn_id
join LIEU_SESSION on LSN_SSN_ID =ssn_id
join LIEU on LEU_ID = LSN_LEU_ID
where SSN_ESN_ID = 15
    and SSN_JOURNEE_ETUDE = 1 
    and LEU_NOM is not null
    and year(ssn_date_debut) = YEAR(GETDATE())

 group by SSN_ID, TME_ID, 
TME_LIBELLE,ssn_date_debut,ssn_date_fin,SSN_NB_JOURS,asn_ssn_id

 union

  select distinct SSN_ID, 
            TME_ID, 
            TME_LIBELLE, 
            convert(varchar,ssn_date_debut,103) as 'Debut',
            CONVERT (varchar,ssn_date_fin,103) as 'Fin',
            SSN_NB_JOURS,
            COUNT (atr_id) as 'Total'
from SESSION
left join INTERVENANT on ITV_SSN_ID = SSN_ID
left join ACTEUR on ITV_ATR_ID = ATR_ID
join theme on tme_id = ssn_tme_id
join ETAT_SESSION on esn_id = ssn_esn_id
join LIEU_SESSION on LSN_SSN_ID =ssn_id
join LIEU on LEU_ID = LSN_LEU_ID
where SSN_ESN_ID = 15
and SSN_JOURNEE_ETUDE = 1 
and LEU_NOM is not null
and year(ssn_date_debut) = YEAR(GETDATE())

 group by SSN_ID, TME_ID, 
TME_LIBELLE,ssn_date_debut,ssn_date_fin,SSN_NB_JOURS,ITV_SSN_ID
```

Comment: please show your query you used to get the shown result.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. That *looks* like SSMS, which is used to connect to SQL Server. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using. As for your question, not really sure what your asking. Rather than posting a picture of data, post it as `text` (that's what data is after all), or, even better as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. Post the code you've written so far, and the results you are after.

Comment: Select columns SSN_ID to FIN sum total and group by columns ssn_id to FIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A derived query approach to get SUM on a total column:

```
SELECT SSN_ID, TIME_ID, TIME_LIBELLE, DEBUT, FIN, SSN_NB_JOURS, SUM(Total) as Total
FROM
(
-- Your original SELECT with UNION
SELECT .. FROM ..
UNION ALL
SELECT .. FROM ..
UNION ALL
SELECT .. FROM ..
) d
GROUP BY SSN_ID, TIME_id, TIME_LIBELLE, DEBUT, FIN, SSN_NB_JOURS
```

Such way should be a valid syntax on both: mysql and sql server

Answer (score 1):

Use as

select(
select distinct (all columns except the last one) from table) , (select sum(total) from table)